# Кеширование картинок Nginx & Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, кэширование

Для кеширования картинок (nginx) у меня на сейте прописано правило:

```
location ~* \.(gif|ico|jpe?g|png)$ {
             expires     1w;
    }
```

Сами картинки хранятся в ларавеле в папке `site/storage/app/dir`
и есть картинки из `/site/public/img` по итогу фалы из `/site/public/img` после кеширования доступны а из `site/storage/app/dir` нет - отдают 404.

Примечание в структуре `site/storage/app/dir` вместо `dir` могут другие папки например `slider` `category` `shop`

Comment: Приложите полный конфиг nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы уверены что картинки из папки storage вообще должны быть доступны? По-умолчанию все доступные клиентам ресурсы хранятся в папке public и ресурсы для фронта отдаются по параметру public_path()/ссылка на файл.

У меня к примеру в папке storage находятся "исходники" файлов, а в папке public уже обработанные, сжатые и подготовленные для клиентов

Comment: В данном случае картинки загруженные юзером хранятся в storage и для доступа к ним используется роутер

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего заведите папку [public_path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk)()/upload с правами на запись для пользователя www-data.

storage_path() используется для того, что не должно быть доступно публично.

То что выделаете сложно назвать [кешированием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88) т.к. никак не увеличивает скорость доступа. Это бесполезное дублирование файлов на диске.

Часть конфига nginx который вы прислали вполне подойдет Вам на начальном этапе.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге пришлось сохранять все в `public` так как при другом подходе терял в скорости.